# Локализация веб приложения

Tags: javascript, frontend, локализация, httpbackend

Интересуют не конкретные библиотеки (они легко гуглятся, да и если хочется, то и самому написать такую не сложно. Хотя если посоветуете что-то интересное или популярное - отдельный плюсик), а подход в целом.

Где осуществлять локализацию? на фронте или на сервере? Я могу использовать Java + Spring с уже встроенной поддержкой локализации, но получается как то не красиво, сервер получается вмешивается во фронтэнд. С другой стороны если генерировать всё с помощью js, поисковики могут это не подхватить, нужно выполнять js код (хотя может это и не нужно, переводят то обычно только интерфейс).

В общем мысли у меня на этот счет есть, но может всё давным давно решено, а я просто тут велосипеды горожу )

Comment: Так вы определитесь, текстовую информацию формирует бэк или фронт?

Comment: Я могу её формировать и так, и так. Мне интересно, какой подход лучше (или более распространен)